# which version of Opencv should I use?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm a beginner in ROS. Currently, I'm trying to use a camera to locate and identify the color balls by the OpenCV package, but depend on my research I found that there has two version of OpenCV, one is OpenCV 2 and OpenCV 3.

So what is different between this two OpenCV? And which one will be more suitable for me?

By the way, I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit indigo.

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235056/which-version-of-opencv-should-i-use?/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, both of them are great, if you have not learned `openCV`, just to learn `opencv3` since it have some different definitions of static parameters and this version has a better frame than `opencv2`.

However, when you want to use `openCV3` , you need to be really careful since some algorithms like `SURF` are not built directly in a traditional way, which means maybe you need to spend several hours to build the developing environment with the help of documents.Besides, lots of existing codes are wrote with `opencv2`,so be careful if you want to make an old package ,there will be many problems. :)

If you want to know more about the difference between `opencv2` and `opencv3`, I think you should go to opencv's [website](http://opencv.org)

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-24**:
Thank you so much. I think I will choose use opencv2 since there will be many problems if I'm doing something wrong.